# Detect duplicate code on tests with sonar

Tags: java, junit, sonarqube

Is it possible to enable [SonarQube](http://www.sonarqube.org/) to check duplicate code on jUnit tests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's currently not possible.

Comment: Wow, I was expecting at least some crazy workaround, do you know if is it even planned for a future release?

Comment: We plan to work on unit tests: being able to apply some checks to unit test code (others than PMD Unit Test checks) and why not detection of duplication. But it is not in our short term roadmap for now. If you want to detect duplication on your unit tests, you have to analyze them as a new SonarQube project and point sonar.sources to the directory containing your unit tests. Feel free to vote for http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SONAR-3733 as well.